# How to make the decrypt function for this encrypt function I made?

Tags: python, encryption, cryptography

I have this encrypt function:

```
def encrypt(password):
    for i in (password):
          not_Encrpyted = ''.join(dict_Chiper[i] for i in password)
          Encrpyted = ''.join(reversed(not_Encrpyted))
return Encrpyted
```

Basically, the dict I have for this function consists of 12 random chars, for example the letter 'a' will be replaced by in 'nqwv62d...' until 12 chars. I have tried making the function but it doesn't work.

The way to dechiper it in my mind is to split it at 12 chars and then reverse it again and find it in dict_Dechiper I made. This is the dict. I don't know if it's wrong or not. Do correct me if this is wrong.

```
dict_Dechiper = {v: k for k, v in dict_Chiper.items()}
```

Please help me make this program. Any help is appreciated! Thank you in advance! :)

EDIT: I deleted the line under def function and it works. Thanks for the pythonic notice to azro!

Comment: Could share a dict_cipher example ? Why do you iterate twice over password,in the loop and in the list comprehension, this does just do X times the same stuff, exactly the same stuff

Comment: dict_Chiper = {
    'a' : "K2uC2tgEVBn4",
    'A' : "lpEFn2e39EFN",
    'b' : "zz45tTn8u4o0",
    'B' : "L293dsfn28dn",
    'c' : "N935efQef3JH"}
This is the example of the dict I use for the encrypt function.
I dont know about the double iteration but it actually works haha. I'll try using only 1 iteration.
The problem is that I cant seem to make the decrypt function.

Comment: You want like `abc -> Ys13ArLoN8aQTiF6uwh4MUnrVROPjk4JWi60 -> abc` ?

Comment: yeah so when I encrypt the abc will be replaced with my dict and will be reversed. But when I entered the dict strings, it will revert back to the abc so this way I can know what the real password  is according to my dict

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ENCRYPT** : Firstly you `encrypt` method does X times the same thing (X is the len of password), for each letter you compute the whole encrypted result, you don't need to, just for each letter get the value from `dict_cipher`

```
def encrypt(password):
    encrypted = ''
    for i in password:
        encrypted += dict_cipher[i]
    return "".join(reversed(encrypted))
```

**DECRYPT** as the last operation of `encrypt` is reversing, here it should be the first, then read each bloc of 12 and find the letter in `dict_decipher`

```
def decrypt(encrypted):
    decrypted = ''
    encrypted = "".join(reversed(encrypted))
    for i in range(0, len(encrypted), 12):
        part = encrypted[i:i + 12]
        decrypted += dict_decipher[part]
    return decrypted
```

---

With a demo

```
# Fill both dicts
for a in (ascii_letters + digits):
    dict_cipher[a] = "".join(sample(ascii_letters + digits, 12))
dict_decipher = {v: k for k, v in dict_cipher.items()}

print(dict_cipher)    # {'a': 'eBx8zu62KPGi',   'b': '2ofrIamwV7XJ',   'c': '01PJWsiIqajl',   ...
print(dict_decipher)  # {'eBx8zu62KPGi': 'a',   '2ofrIamwV7XJ': 'b',   '01PJWsiIqajl': 'c',   ...

value = "abc"
ee = encrypt(value)
print(ee)  # ljaqIisWJP10JX7VwmaIrfo2iGPK26uz8xBe

dd = decrypt(ee)
print(dd)  # abc
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It helps me so much! Deeply appreciated! :)